# Control of relay board via http

Tags: python, http

I have a relay control board with an ethernet interface. The rather brief Chinglish data tells me to switch relays off and on using the following format 192.168.1.x/30000/yy in a web browser. This works well, but I don't understand what I am typing.....The 30000 part is, I presume, a port, as I can change it in a rudimentary webserver on the board. I was expecting to see the port defined following a colon. But what is the third item, the yy? A chunk of data sent after the connection is made? Or sent as part of the intial connection?

Now to the Python bit. I want to send this data from Python. http.client appears to be the way to go, but how can I send that mysterious yy?

I believe I am setting up the connection, but can't find a way to send the yy information.

A similar question only refers to a serial connection - there is only an interface as I describe on this board.

Regards

Comment: `/30000/yy` is the path part of the URL.

Comment: Really? As I say, the primitive website calls the 30000 bit a port. An error in translation?

Comment: I can close this. As bereal says the 30000 is part of the url and not a port (perhaps translator confused port and subdirectory). The following snippet works.    Obviously the 00 will have to become a variable to something useful.        connection = http.client.HTTPConnection(ipA)
connection.request('GET', '/30000/00')

Comment: Probably, the configuration service that runs there uses that value to configure the port. So it's the port value that's passed as a parameter through the URL path (just my guess).

Comment: One more point in case somebody else uses a similar board. They don't like 'GETs' arriving too fast. I put a time.sleep (0,1) between talking to each of the addresses.

Answer (score 0):

`/30000/yy` is the [path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Web_mechanics/What_is_a_URL#path_to_resource) part of the URL. So what you seem to need is to send a `GET` request:

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(host)
conn.request('GET', '/30000/yy')
```